# “Food” in German

Tags: translation, difference

When I was looking for the German equivalent of ***food*** in my dictionary, I’ve noticed that both *Lebensmittel* and *Nahrung* have the same meaning and so does *Essen,* which I had learned before.

While I was trying to find the difference via Google, not only didn’t it solve the problem but also I found some other words with the same meaning like *Nahrungsmittel, Genussmittel, Speise* and *Futter.* [Here](http://www.raetsel-hilfe.de/n-40-nah.html), I just found that *Futter* is animal’s food.

I’m confused: Is there any differences between these words and their usage? Why there are too many words for *food?*

Comment: Don't forget **Ernährung**!

Comment: @Tim: But **Ernährung** is not something you can eat. That makes it rather different from the other words.

Comment: @Hendrik Don't forget the food pyramid.

Comment: Food, groceries, edibles, catering, foodstuffs, nutriment, aliment, provisions, supplies, victuals/vittles, viands, meal, feed, chow, fodder, grub...

Comment: @thei: Yes, this is an instant where _food_ does translate to _Ernährung_, but still I think that it's quite different. (In my above comment, I first wanted to write that _food_ never translates to _Ernährung_, but then realized that this might not be true. Thanks for the nice example!)

Comment: @RegDwight: So, I'll ask the same question on EL&U !

Comment: What about 'cuisine' ?

Comment: There are so many words for food because Germans care about food, and are more nuanced about it than the English, I guess. <g>

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Lebensmittel** is the technical term. You would say "Ein Supermarkt verkauft Lebensmittel"; an official food inspector is called *Lebensmittelkontrolleur*.

**Nahrung** usually stands for nourishment or nutrition, not only referring to food, but also, for example, "Öl ist Nahrung für das Feuer" — "oil feeds the fire".

**Essen** is either the act of eating or the colloquial word for food. "Ich gehe etwas zum Essen einkaufen" ("I'm going to buy something to eat") or "Ich gehe Essen einkaufen".

An example of the difference between *Lebensmittel* and *Essen*: "Er warf die Lebensmittel weg" would refer to throwing away, for example, a full grocery bag or food from the cupboard, whereas "Er warf das Essen weg" would probably rather be getting rid of a prepared meal, or scraping off a plate.

**Speise** is a more antiquated word. It is normally used to refer to something special or formal. Nowadays it is usually found in compounds such as *Speisekarte* (a menu, as in the list of food available in a restaurant) or *Speisesaal* (a dining hall in a castle or a hotel).

Answer (score 29):

**Essen**: if you are talking about the food of a particular meal in an ordinary setting.

> Das Essen ist fertig. (Dinner/lunch is ready.)

**Lebensmittel**: refers to food as goods you can buy and sell, as in food production or food prices.

> Die Lebensmittelpreise sind überdurchschnittlich stark angestiegen.

**Speise**: refers to a particular dish, as in my favourite dish. Can be used instead of *Essen* in a more formal or older context (e.g. Bible translation or poems).

> - Meine Lieblingsspeise.
> - Jesus hat Fisch und Brot bei der Speisung der Fünftausend vermehrt.

**Nahrung** and **Nahrungsmittel**: refers to food as satisfying your needs, compare *nahrhaft*, "nutritious".

**Ernährung** is food in the sense of nutrition or diet.

> Gesunde Ernährung ist die Grundlage eines guten Teints.

**Futter** is used for animal food and can be used for food in informal or regional contexts.

**Fressen** is also used for animal's food.

**Genußmittel** refers to drug-like items that do not primarily satisfy hunger. Think chocolate, coffee, tobacco, etc.

Comment: Nice summary. Can _Essen_ also refer to animal food?

Comment: @Tim: No, you wouldn't say that. You would use the verb *fressen* and *Futter*: *Der Hund hat das ganze Futter gefressen*. The noun *das Fressen* can also be used for animal's food.

Comment: "Essen" has a slightly broader meaning, see RoToRa's answer for an example.

Comment: @Deve: You wouldn’t say ‘Fressen ist fertig’ to a dog, though. Weird as it is, some people would rather say ‘Fressi ist fertig’.

Answer (score 3):

"Lebensmittel" literally translates into "means of life." A better translation may be "foodstuffs." It could be in very raw form, such as unhusked corn, but are things that can be made into a meal.

"Nahrung" refers to things of nutritional value. It can refer not only to food, but to items such as vitamins, or even "cod livers oil" (bad-tasting but rich in protein).

Essen is prepared food, or what you eat, basically the dinner on your table.

Speise refers not only to "food" but to (fine) "dining," and refers to a dinner that is well prepared and is better than mere "Essen. A restaurant meal or restaurant quality meal prepared at home would "qualify."

Futter translates into "fodder" and is food for **animals.**